# Flutter firebase auth try catch not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i'm using firebase auth, when I try call the method await FirebaseAuth.instance .signInWithEmailAndPassword (email: email, password: password); and the credentials are wrong, try catch not working. the output message is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5Fo.png)
I using firebase_core: ^1.0.0
and firebase_auth: ^1.0.0

I've already tried what the documentation recommends but still can't find a solution. I have runner flutter doctor, but it does not indicate anything strange.
Someone help me for the solution?

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7356816/110394113-7b944700-8031-11eb-95f6-1e2b9cac5483.png

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: As mentioned, please use Stack Overflow's tools to format your code instead of using an image.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Please post the relevant code for more help.</sup>

But it seems you're missing the type for the error.

Try something like:

```
try {
    //...
} catch (Exception error) { // include type

}
```

Comment: I've already tried, but it just ignores the try catch...

Comment: @JoseMaría Could you post your code and the error, preferably in text?